# why repeat link style and metatag in pages at yii2

Tags: hyperlink, yii2, metatag

I use yii2 framwork.
My set link style css with:
`$this->registerCssFile` command and set pages metatag  in my controller.

But when page is load,link style and mettags Twice are load.

Plz see under link:

view-source:http://designtk.ir/

Comment: show some examples of your layouts/main.php

Comment: maybe you have <?php $this->head() ?> twice in your layout file

Comment: tnx very much BHoft(GAMITG).your comment is true. <?php $this->head() ?> twice load in my layout file.

Answer (score 0):

You either have loaded the header twice check your /layout.php for repeated

`<?php $this->head() ?>`

or you have registered the core scripts twice

```
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCoreScript('jquery');
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCoreScript('jquery-ui.min.js');
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCoreScript('jquery-ui.min.css');
```